# Как правильно создать выпадающий список, без использования модальности?

Tags: 1с

Код:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура Поле3НачалоВыбора(Элемент, ДанныеВыбора, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    СписокВыбора = Новый СписокЗначений;
    СписокВыбора.Добавить("Самовывоз");
    СписокВыбора.Добавить("Доставка");
    ВыбЭлемент = ЭтаФорма.ВыбратьИзСписка(СписокВыбора, Элемент, 0);
    Если НЕ ВыбЭлемент = Неопределено Тогда
    СпособПолучения = ВыбЭлемент.Значение;
    КонецЕсли;
    СтандартнаяОбработка = Ложь;
    ОписаниеОповещения = Новый ОписаниеОповещения("ТестовыйВводСтроки", ЭтаФорма);
    ПоказатьВводСтроки(ОписаниеОповещения, СписокВыбора, "Введите строковое значение");
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ТестовыйВводСтроки(ПолученноеЗначение, ПереданныеПараметры) Экспорт
Сообщить("Вы ввели " + ПолученноеЗначение);
КонецПроцедуры
```

Есть `Реквизит1` с типом: `СписокЗначений`

Открывается всплывающее окно с сообщением: Использование модальных окон в данном режиме запрещено!

Как это исправить? Чтобы выводился только результат выбора.

Answer (score 1):

[Вариант №1](https://tugle.ru/?q=1%D0%A1%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Вариант №2: учитесь работать с синтакс-помощником
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]